# Convert string into Date value in R

Tags: r, date

I have a array containing date values in a unusual way.

```
datevalue <- c("6m6d", "6m10d","12m31d")
```

"m" stands for: month, "d" stands for: day
I want to convert it into 4 digits date value for further calculation.

`6m6d : 0606`

`6m10d : 0610`

`12m31d : 1231`

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think you can achieve that with : `format(as.Date(datevalue, format = "%mm%dd"), "%m%d")`
(Note that `as.Date(datevalue, format = "%mm%dd")` returns the date for the current year)